# RFID/ NFC based Buss pass system

Tags: java, c#

I'm trying to work on Buss Pass System for my FYP. I am familiar with C# and Java programming languages and I wanted to use a concept where the travelers enter the bus and scan their RFID/NFC tag and if they are approved to board, the system should display **Green Light** if not it should display **Red Light** with a corresponding sound effect. My question for you is what kind of device should I use. Thank you!

Comment: That is a great question but unfortunately too broad for StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you have to decide whether you want some Android mobile phone/tablet to emulate the reader in the bus - consequently you will need to program it in Java.
Or you can decide to go with a RasPi with a NFC reader and use the GPIOs to drive some LEDs.